# SurfaceView Thread IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java, android, multithreading, surfaceview

I am trying to put two parts of my program together. I have a map the user can move around and click on parts of the map. Then it takes them to a new activity displaying the information of what they pressed. My error occurs when the information is displayed. It starts the activity and displays it for a split second, but then restarts the MainActivity. The error seems to be in my thread in my SurfaceView class.

```
public class MapSurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static MapSurface rs;
    private Context c;
    private SurfaceHolder sh;

    private RenderSurfaceThread render_thread;

    private static Map map;

    public MapSurface(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
        super(context, attr);

        c = context;
        sh = getHolder();

        sh.addCallback(this);

        render_thread = new RenderSurfaceThread();

        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static MapSurface getInstance() {
        return rs;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        rs = this;
        map = new Map(c.getResources(), R.drawable.map, getWidth(), getHeight());
        render_thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        render_thread.stopThread();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return MapTouchHandler.handleTouch(this, map, e);
    }

    public final Map getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void requestRedraw() {
        render_thread.throttleThread();
    }

    public int getState() {
        return render_thread.thread_state;
    }

    public RenderSurfaceThread getThread() {
        return render_thread;
    }

    class RenderSurfaceThread extends Thread {

        // Some thread state variables.
        public static final int THREAD_UNDEFINED = -1;
        public static final int THREAD_NEW = 0;
        public static final int THREAD_IDLE = 1;
        public static final int THREAD_EXECUTING = 2;
        public static final int THREAD_KILL = 3;
        public static final int THREAD_DEAD = 4;

        // Thread state variable.
        private int thread_state = THREAD_UNDEFINED;

        // Idle lock object
        private final Object RUN_LOCK = new Object();

        private RenderSurfaceThread() {
            setState(THREAD_NEW);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            setState(THREAD_EXECUTING);

            while (thread_state != THREAD_KILL) {
                map.transformImage();
                doDraw();

                // Thread will idle until redraw is requested.
                idleThread();
            }

            setState(THREAD_DEAD);
        }

        private void doDraw() {
            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = sh.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (sh) {
                    // Critical section. Do not allow mRun to be set false until
                    // we are sure all canvas draw operations are complete.
                    //
                    // If mRun has been toggled false, inhibit canvas
                    // operations.
                    synchronized (RUN_LOCK) {
                        if (thread_state == THREAD_EXECUTING) {
                            // Do our drawing here
                            canvas.drawBitmap(map.getMapBitmap(), 0, 0, null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (canvas != null) {
                    sh.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }

        private void idleThread() {
            setState(THREAD_IDLE);
            try {
                do {
                    synchronized (sh) {
                        sh.wait();
                    }
                } while (thread_state != THREAD_EXECUTING); // Ensure the notify
                                                            // means that it is
                                                            // time to execute
                // and not something else
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }

        private void throttleThread() {
            synchronized (sh) {
                setState(THREAD_EXECUTING);
                sh.notifyAll();
            }
        }

        private void setState(int state) {
            synchronized (sh) {
                synchronized (RUN_LOCK) {
                    assert (thread_state != THREAD_DEAD);
                    thread_state = state;
                    RUN_LOCK.notifyAll();
                }
            }
        }

        private void stopThread() {
            // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or
            // else
            // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
            boolean retry = true;
                do {
                    if (thread_state == THREAD_IDLE) {
                        setState(THREAD_KILL);
                        throttleThread();
                    } else {
                        try {
                            RUN_LOCK.wait();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                } while (thread_state != THREAD_KILL
                        && thread_state != THREAD_DEAD);

                while (retry) {
                    try {
                        join();
                        retry = false;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Logcat Output:

```
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721): java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: object not locked by thread before wait()
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at com.eecs448.kuville.ui.MapSurface$RenderSurfaceThread.stopThread(MapSurface.java:183)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at com.eecs448.kuville.ui.MapSurface$RenderSurfaceThread.access$1(MapSurface.java:171)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at com.eecs448.kuville.ui.MapSurface.surfaceDestroyed(MapSurface.java:53)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:555)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:232)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:7682)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1071)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1071)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1071)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1071)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1227)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-07 00:16:18.235: E/AndroidRuntime(2721):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-07 00:16:18.285: E/InputDispatcher(1201): channel 'b1404ba8 com.eecs448.kuville/com.eecs448.kuville.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
12-07 00:16:18.285: E/InputDispatcher(1201): channel 'b15a72b8 com.eecs448.kuville/com.eecs448.kuville.Building (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
12-07 00:16:18.285: E/InputDispatcher(1201): channel 'b158bbf8 com.eecs448.kuville/com.eecs448.kuville.main.MapActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201): *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8351)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8221)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:8900)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:8455)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerService.java:8437)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201):     at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:1211)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1737)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/JavaBinder(1201):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201): Activity Manager Crash
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8351)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:8221)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:8900)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:8455)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrash(ActivityManagerService.java:8437)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201):    at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:1211)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201):    at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1737)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201):    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
12-07 00:16:18.335: E/ActivityManager(1201):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather Doing this MapSurface Sorcery. Why not you opting for Google Map v2.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Add Any kind of [Marker](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html) on it and listen their action and do whatever you want.

Maps are 3d and map pieces works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you handle onSaveInstanceState like this

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putBoolean("inprogress", true);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    boolean isNew = true;
    if(savedInstanceState != null)
        isNew = !savedInstanceState.getBoolean("inprogress");
    initActivity(isNew);
}
```

You need to differentiate whether main activity created at the beginning of the app or after save configuration

Comment: I do not see initActivity() as a method I can call, is it supposed to be something else?

Comment: It would be one of your methods to initialize activity, I just wanted to show that you need to not create things twice and not start threads again and so on. isNew if its false means you do not have to initialize some of your fields and threads